# Is it safe to use Bleachbit in a ext4 filesystem with journaling?

Tags: filesystem, ext4, privacy, bleachbit

I want to shred a file, making it unrecoverable. I normally use the command 'bleachbit -s file'. When I was searching about it, I found out that the journaling in ext4 makes a copy of the file somewhere else, that isn't deleted even after the file was shredded. In another forum, someone said the file resulted from the journaling deletes itself after some time.

Is it true? Can i trust only Bleachbit to wipe my files, knowing they will be unrecoverable after some time, or the journaling feature makes it useless, because, even after this, they will still be recoverable?

Sorry if it is a stupid question. I'm somewhat new to Linux and still don't know much. And sorry for my English, I'm more of a reader than a writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is bleachbit "safe" - yes. Running bleach bit itself will not damage your system, however, you can do damage if you use it to remove things you should not or if you misuse it.

There is a difference between deleting a file or formatting a partition and over writing the file with new data.

In the first case, deletion or formatting, you can potentially recover the file as the data or contents have not been removed from the disk.

for details, see testdisk, photorec, and similar data recovery tools.

See also - http://www.ufsexplorer.com/und_fmt.php and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/file_recovery and / other technical documents of the various tools.

This first type of data recovery may or may not use the ext4 journal.

The second scenario is where the data is over written, as is the case with your use of bleachbit. You can use several other tools to do this if you so desire.

In this case, the data is gone, beyond recovery. The guttman theory has been debunked =)

see http://www.nber.org/sys-admin/overwritten-data-guttman.html or similar

Comment: So, if I use the 'bleachbit -s' command to shred a file, I can be sure it will be impossible to recover?

Comment: @Lamarck'sson Yes, if you use ext4 with data=ordered mode, which is the default. For extra guarantee for sensitive information, you use the really slow "overwrite free space" option. See also the [BleachBit documentation on shredding](http://docs.bleachbit.org/doc/shred-files-and-wipe-disks.html) for more

Answer (score 1):

I think for ext4 and the default options this should not be an issue.

quote from the shred man page. A good read I would say.

```
In  the  case  of  ext3 file systems, the above disclaimer applies 
(and shred is thus of limited effectiveness) only in data=journal mode
```

You can check this by doing

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

and checking the `data=XXX` parts.

This of course only applies if nothing fundamental changed with ext4.

(Mostly taken from this post on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/70521/securely-deleting-files-on-linux-journaled-filesystem))